# Can i nest a foreach within foreach?

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I have an `array`: `$categories = array("item1", "item2", "item3");`
I also have three arrays: `$item1Array = array("hi", "items");`, `$item2Array = array("hi", "items");`, `$item3Array = array("hi", "items");`
I stated a foreach like this:

```
foreach ($categories as &$value) {
    echo "<optgroup label='" . $value . "'>';
    $nextArray = $value . "Array";
    foreach($nextArray as &$nextValue) {
        echo "<option value='" . $nextValue . "'>" . $nextValue . "</option>";
    }
}
```

but it get an error `Warning: invalid argument supplied for foreach()`.
Is there a way I can achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course, but as you can clearly see from the syntax highlighting of your post, you used a `'` instead of a `"` at the end of the "optgroup" line.

Also, you could just use a nested array:

```
$categories = Array(
  "item1"=>Array("hi","items"),
  "item2"=>Array("hi","items"),
  "item3"=>Array("hi","items"),
);
foreach($categories as $key=>$array) {
  echo "<optgroup label='".$key."'>";
  foreach($array as $value) {
    echo "<option>".$value."</option>";
  }
  echo "</optgroup>";
}
```

Comment: If I use a `'` at the end of that line instead of a `"` it wouldn't work because the `'` is inside the quotes. It echos as `<optgroup='label'>`

Comment: I tried the nested arrays and it worked perfectly! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you could, by `${$nextArray}`. but notice **named variables is not good practice**, you could use associative array instead.

And note you don't need to use reference in this case.

```
$categories = array("item1", "item2", "item3");
$item1Array = array("hi", "items");
$item2Array = array("hi", "items");
$item3Array = array("hi", "items");

foreach ($categories as $value) {
    echo "<optgroup label='" . $value . "'>";
    $nextArray = $value . "Array";
    foreach(${$nextArray} as $nextValue) {
        echo "<option value='" . $nextValue . "'>" . $nextValue . "</option>";
    }
}
```